# How to use interactive debugger when shiny app runs in background job?

Tags: r, shiny

At first, I will show MRE:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("browser", "Browser")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
 observeEvent(input$browser, {
   browser()
 })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When this runs in R console, after clicking on button named "Browser", the app stops and user can use interactive debugger, where e.g. can write `input$browser` and see it has value `1`.

However, I'm not able to use interactive debugger when shiny app runs as a background job. How can I do this? Maybe it could be even possible to keep running app (in a background) and be able to use interactive debugger in R Console (so app won't stop)?

Comment: Not sure this is simple or even possible. If the shiny app is running in the background it is basically running a secondary terminal (headless). It'll have it's own Process ID (`Sys.getpid()`). I would expect this to require you to attach this session to a live terminal (which is way out of my league and seems to be near-impossible on linux [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-do-i-attach-a-terminal-to-a-detached-process)). Maybe [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/01/debugging-parallel-code-with-dbs/) could work?

Comment: I undestand, thank you! I think I will leave this as it is now, I do not consider myself skilled in this and don't have time now to learn